# The <span> Tag with {float:right] Stretches Container in IE7

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an A tag button with Span inside to hold icons. It works well in all browsers. WHen I apply float:right to shift Span to the right side it also works fine in all browsers (Firefox, IE8+, etc.) except IE7 (I know... but I need to fix it).

```
 <a href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>Link</a>
```

So, IE7 works fine when SPAN is floated left. However, once it is floated right it stretches the A tag container 100%.

I do not wish to change the structure of HTML, i.e. insert another span to handle IE7 only or move SPAN right of text, but I do want to fix it with CSS though what I tried did not work well for me yet.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/QeQSQ/1/ (IE7 works OK when SPAN is on left side)

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/QeQSQ/2/ (IE7 does NOT work because SPAN is on right side and container is stretching)

Comment: Try adding overflow:visible to your <a> tag. Works for the stretchy button bug, not sure it will fix this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position it absolutely instead ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/QeQSQ/3/)):

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:1em;
}
a span{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    display:block;
    height:14px;
    width:15px;

}
```

Or, another [better] solution would be to add the character via `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/QeQSQ/4/)):

```
<a href="#" class="site">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="account">Link</a>
```

```css
a{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
}
a.site:before {
    content:"» ";
}
a.account:after {
    content:" »";
}
```

***Note:** This doesn't work in IE7 at all (no additional text appears), but it also doesn't introduce any bugs.*

Answer (score 0):

remove the float:left and instead give the span display inline-block with an ie7 workaround:

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    padding:5px;
}


a span{   
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1; 
    *display: inline;
    height:14px;
    width:15px;    
}​
```

updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QeQSQ/5/

also an article about the ie7 inline-block workaround: http://flipc.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/damn-ie7-and-inline-block.html